# operation on string items in python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I found some unexpected behavior while trying to edit strings in a dictionary (python 3.8.9.0), the new value does not make it into the string.

A dictionary of lists appends as expected

```py
a = {'a':[]}
for k, v in a.items():
   v+=['o']
   
a
Out[24]: {'a': ['o']}
```

A dictionary of strings does not update:

```
a = {'a':'a'}
for k, v in a.items():
   v+='o'
   
a
Out[27]: {'a': 'a'}
```

Comment: Strings are _immutable_, this shouldn't be unexpected.

Comment: try it with `a[k] += 'o'` instead

Comment: @jonrsharpe if strings are immutable how does the += operator work in general?

Comment: The augmented assignment operators work however they're implemented on the class in question. On lists it appends to and returns the original list, on strings it returns a new string.

Comment: @Techniquab That's a great question. `+=` on lists is notoriously confusing. For example, [for a list in a tuple, it works, but also raises an error](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-does-a-tuple-i-item-raise-an-exception-when-the-addition-works).

Comment: Could you edit your post to ask an actual question? I want to post an answer, but I don't know how to frame it. Maybe you want to ask, "Why can't I update a string in a dict, while I can update a list just fine?" If it helps, [ask] has tips on how to write a clear question.

Comment: The behavior of names and values in Python can be confusing, even when you think you understand how they work. ;) Please see this classic article:  https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, adding another string even in place leads to a new string, but you can use dict setting for the same thing.

```py
d = {}

d[1] = "a"
print(id(d[1]), d[1])  # 4302987632 a

s = d[1]
print(id(s), s)  # 4302987632 a

s += "c"
print(id(s), s)  # 4672398256 ac

d[1] += "d"
print(id(d[1]), d[1])  # 4646283568 ad but this time it is placed in the dict
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because lists are mutable, and strings are not. To get the more "expected" (by some definition) behavior, modify the original dictionary **value**. Example:

```
a = {'a':'a'}
for k, v in a.items():
   v += 'o'
print(a)
# {'a': 'a'}

for k, v in a.items():
   a[k] += 'o'
print(a)
# {'a': 'ao'}
```